# How to measure RUs when executing CreateItemStreamAsync()?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

How to measure consumed RUs in Azure Cosmos DB when creating a new item using .Net SDK v3's `CreateItemStreamAsync()?`

Unlike available Microsoft documentation for non stream alternatives, this one does not return `RequestCharge` property.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream APIs return the raw service response, they expose the service headers in `ResponseMessage.Headers`.

Request Charge is a [response header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-response-headers): `x-ms-request-charge`.

This is available as a [promoted property in the Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.headers?view=azure-dotnet#properties) type.

```
ResponseMessage response = await container.CreateItemStreamAsync(...);

double ruCharge = response.Headers.RequestCharge;
```